# Fast stack switching under x86-64

Tags: c, linux, windows, assembly, x86-64

What's the minimal code to switch stacks under x86-64? I'm trying to implement fibers under Windows and Linux, without getcontext or setjmp + inline assembly. Is it really as simple as swapping $rsp and $rbp? 'Cause I could do that easily. I'm just not sure how to go about it. I'm rusty on my x86-64 knowledge.

Comment: I'm not sure what the fastest method is, but you may want to take a look at [libcoro](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libcoro.html), which has a bunch of implementations. Also, I've been told (by the author) [this](https://github.com/Shelwien/stegdict/blob/master/Lib/coro2b.inc) is pretty fast. On Windows there is a [fibers API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686919(v=vs.85).aspx), that's pretty minimal for your code…

Comment: You'll need _some_ asm because you can't switch rsp without it. Also, depending on where you put your (e.g.) `coroutine_switchto()` calls, you'll need to save/restore a number of callee saved regs and [possibly] the flags register as well

Comment: The question is a little confusing. Do you want to know the *easiest* way to switch stacks or the *fastest* way or the *smallest-code-size* way? The title says fast but the body of the question says minimal code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing RSP to point to a different stack has to be done as part of a context-switch that saves all the registers from the old thread/fiber and loads the saved architectural state from the new register.  Not just RBP, but all of RAX-RDI and R8-R15, and RIP (via `jmp` or `ret`).  And all the other call-preserved architectural state, which includes xmm6-15 on Windows x86-64, I think.  If your code ever changes MXCSR or the x87 control register, you need to save/restore those too.

But if you **put your context-switch in a `noinline` function**, the compiler will make code for a regular function call (which effectively returns much later in time), and function calls already clobber all the call-clobbered registers.  You don't have to save the caller's zmm0-31, or MPX `bnd` registers, or RFLAGS.  So it's probably not worth using `xsaveopt` / `xrstor` to save FPU / SIMD state.

If you leave other regs unmodified, you will have a Bad Time, because switching to a new stack and new code with old registers is basically the same thing as clobbering call-preserved registers out from under the compiler, i.e. violating the ABI.

You don't need to save `RFLAGS` because the only things that can change in user-space are the condition codes, and those are call-clobbered.  The ABI / calling convention already requires that DF is clear on function call/return.

Answer (score 1):

The context switch is determined by the ABI (callee-saved registers must be preserved).
[boost.context](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/context/doc/html/index.html) already provides a implementation for several architectures.
[boost.fiber](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/fiber/doc/html/index.html) is an abstraction for fibers with an std::thread-like API based on boost.context.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does provide [setjmp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setjmp), [setjmp3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/setjmp3) and [longjmp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/longjmp). They also provide [Using setjmp/longjmp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/using-setjmp-longjmp).

code example below can be found at [Explain setjmp() and longjmp() Functions in Standard C Library with Examples](https://www.sanfoundry.com/c-questions-setjmp-longjmp-functions-standard-library-uses/)

```
/* setjmp_longjmp.c -- program handles error through 'setjmp()' */
/* and longjmp() */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

/* declare variable of type jmp_buf */
jmp_buf resume_here;

void hello(void);

int main(void)
{
    int ret_val;

    /* Initialize 'resume_here' by calling setjmp() */
    if (setjmp(resume_here)) {


    printf("After \'longjump()\', back in \'main()\'\n");
        printf("\'jump buffer variable \'resume_here\'\' becomes "
                  "INVALID!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("\'setjmp()\' returns first time\n");
        hello();
    }

    return 0;
}

void hello(void)
{
    printf("Hey, I'm in \'hello()\'\n");
    longjmp(resume_here, 1);

    /* other code */
    printf("can't be reached here because I did longjmp!\n");
}
```

Comment: In ISO C, longjmp is only valid when the `jmp_buf` was saved by a parent function, not a sibling.  i.e. you can go back up the same callstack, not switch a sibling stack.  Does MS's `setjmp3` do something different to allow for stack switching?

Comment: I don't believe it does, it just allows additional parameters for context.

Comment: there's no need to escape `'` inside `"` and vice versa

Comment: and instead of `printf("Hey, I'm in \'hello()\'\n");` just use `puts("Hey, I'm in 'hello()'");`